# remove only 1 type item in datafream without using groupby

Tags: pandas

| item ID | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | B |
| 4 | B |
| 5 | B |
| 5 | A |

---

I'm trying to find out which item has only 1 type.
In this data, answer is [1,5].

1 has both A & B. It's good.
2 only has A, so fault.
3 only has B, so fault.
4 only has B, even it appeared twice, fault.
5 has both A & B. So whatever its order, It's good.

so I try this code

```
for i in data.groupby("item ID"):  # pandas
    _ = len(i[1].type.unique())
    if _ == 1:
        data.drop(i[1].index, inplpace=True)
```

it works well, But too slow.

please someone tell me faster way.

Comment: There is per group always 2 values? Not possible 3 values?

Comment: @jezrael In this case, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) for get number of unique values per groups and test if not 1 value by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html), filter rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = data[data.groupby("item ID")['type'].transform('nunique').ne(1)]
```

Without groupby if there are always 2 or 1 values per group by column `item ID` is possible solution with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://%5Bandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df = data[~data.duplicated(keep=False) & data.duplicated('item ID', keep=False)]
print (df)
   item ID type
0        1    A
1        1    B
6        5    B
7        5    A
```

For get unique `item ID` use:

```
s = data.groupby("item ID")['type'].nunique()
L = s.index[s.ne(1)].tolist()
print (L)
[1, 5]
```

---

```
mask = ~data.duplicated(keep=False) & data.duplicated('item ID', keep=False)
L = data.loc[mask, 'item ID'].unique().tolist()
print (L)
[1, 5]
```

**Performance**:

```
np.random.seed(20)

df = pd.DataFrame({'item ID':np.random.randint(3000, size=5000),
                   'type':np.random.choice(['A','B'], size=5000)})

#[3908 rows x 2 columns]
data = df.sort_values('item ID').groupby('item ID').head(2)
print (data)


In [51]: %%timeit
    ...: for i in data.groupby("item ID"):  # pandas
    ...:     _ = len(i[1].type.unique())
    ...:     if _ == 1:
    ...:         data.drop(i[1].index, inplace=True)
    ...:         
119 ms ± 1.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#BeRT2me solution
In [52]: %timeit data.groupby('item ID').filter(lambda x: x['type'].nunique() > 1)
709 ms ± 10.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

```
In [53]: %timeit data[data.groupby("item ID")['type'].transform('nunique').ne(1)]
1.75 ms ± 14.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [54]: %timeit data[~data.duplicated(keep=False)&data.duplicated('item ID', keep=False)]
2.1 ms ± 192 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Probably slower than yours, but how does `data.set_index('item ID')[data.groupby('item ID').nunique().gt(1)].dropna().reset_index()` do?